# PreApplicationStartMethod called multiple times

Tags: c#, double-checked-locking

A method in a class in an assembly decorated by `PreApplicationStartMethod` attribute is meant to be called before `Application_Start` event is fired.
For example, this is how `BuildManager` gets to know what assemblies (in addition to ones in the web application) to reference when compiling a page, a control, or a view.
It is quite natural to expect the pointed out method to be called only once -- after all it it part of an initialization process, which normally occurs only once per application. (I will only mention an attempt to create a database twice!!)
After adding some trace calls I discovered that the method (not always, sometimes!) is called twice.
In order to avoid this I added a boolean field to the class to prevent multiple calls like this:

```
   private static bool initialzed;

   public static void Initialize()

        if (PreApplicationInit.initialzed == false)
        {
            // perform the initialization here
            // ...
            PreApplicationInit.initialzed = true;
        }
    }
```

To my surprise the method got called twice again. An obvious suspicion was that it is called on two different threads (despite this makes a little sense in an initialization code).
[Double-check locking](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html) was an obvious solution to such a problem, so I changed the code like this:

```
   private static readonly object SyncRoot = new Object();

   private static bool initialzed;

   public static void Initialize()
   {
        if (PreApplicationInit.initialzed == false)
        {
            lock (PreApplicationInit.SyncRoot)
            {
                if (PreApplicationInit.initialzed == false)
                {
                    // perform the initialization here
                    // ...
                    PreApplicationInit.initialzed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What is really making this an issue is the fact that the code is called from native code. Tthis is the $CALLER from a tracepoint:

```
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

So, my question is obvious, I guess: what (*and more important why!*) invokes a method denoted to be called before `Application_Start` event more than once?

Comment: If it's a web app, it's possible there could be more than one instance in the application pool. Try changing your IIS settings - reduce the worker instance pool size to 1 and see what happens.

Comment: Are you having C++ global variables? The C++ statics are initialized when the unmanaged dll is loaded. For cyclic dependencies between C++ objects the initialization order is undefined (see static initialization order fiasco). Try using a debugger to check where the "odd" double init is coming from.

Comment: @Baldrick: yes, it is possible, but does not happen. The app is still tested, requests are from a single browser, single tab.

Comment: @Alois Kraus: no, no C++ whatsoever.

Comment: The static ctor is thread safe in itself. The clr will lock access to it. Such a double init could happen if you have cyclic dependencies between managed statics. In that case you can see a partially initialized object. See http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/04/07/type-initializer-circular-dependencies/

Comment: @AloisKraus: yes, static ctors are a natural alternative to double-check locking. However, my code (PreApplicationStartMethod-ed) is called by native code, most probably one that IIS hosts. This makes me think that the situation you describe is quite alike. 
Moreover, there's a single static ctor in the code, which does not reference any code outside the class, defining the method in question. 
And yes, I read the article -- it describes interesting, yet quite an awkward scenario, I guess... Any other ideas? Let me remind again: what calls the PreApp... method, Initialize() in my case?

Comment: I cannot answer the question who calls Initializes. When guessing does not help you should start debugging.